# Create view with subquery and group by expression in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, group-by, subquery

To retrieve particular data set I had to use a subquery in a select query which is a group by expression as below:

```
SELECT SUM(b.RESERVEDROOMS) AS "Reserved Rooms",
       (SELECT country
          FROM location
         WHERE location_id = b.location_id) AS "Country"
  FROM bookingsRevenue b,
       location l
 WHERE b.location_id = l.location_id 
 GROUP BY b.location_id
```

It works fine and correct data are retrieved but when I try to create a view from it, following error is shown. Could you please help me to resolve this.

> [Error] Execution (21: 74): ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Why are you using a Scalar Subquery?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is a bit of confusion in your source code. The GROUP BY clause isn't correct, also you do not need to use a correlated subquery. 
Try this one:

```
SELECT SUM(b.RESERVEDROOMS) AS "Reserved Rooms", l.country AS "Country"
FROM bookingsRevenue b
JOIN location l ON (b.location_id = l.location_id)
GROUP BY l.country;
```

If you want also the location_id to be grouped then:

```
SELECT SUM(b.RESERVEDROOMS) AS "Reserved Rooms", b.location_id, l.country AS "Country"
FROM bookingsRevenue b
JOIN location l ON (b.location_id = l.location_id)
GROUP BY b.location_id, l.country;
```

Comment: Or you could use `MAX( l.country ) AS country`.

Comment: yes I think MAX(l.country) works and just having l.country gives me an error. 
Thanks a lot for your advice !